# WPF Relative binding exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Given a usercontrol bound to a viewmodel defined as follows

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public DataView MyView { get; set; }
    public DataView MyTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and the XAML is roughly marked as follows

```
<Grid>
    <dxg:GridControl AutoPopulateColumns="True" Name="gridControl1" ItemsSource="{ Binding MyView}">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="col1">
                <dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="cmbTypes" 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                            Path=ViewModel.MyTypes}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="col2"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="col3" Width="75"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView Name="tableView1" AutoWidth="True" ShowTotalSummary="True" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
</Grid>
```

bound as follows

```
internal MyViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return (MyViewModel)DataContext; }
    set { DataContext = value; }
}
```

Of course the ComboBox does not show the selections from ListTypes which does have values

Question is - how to reference the ListTypes property of the ViewModel 
from Grid.Column where the Grid is Bound to a DataView MyItems which does not have the property ListTypes, which is at the same level as ListTypes !!!

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, I'd expect the following to work:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                        Path=DataContext.MyTypes}
```

It may be that `Path=ViewModel.MyTypes` is not working simply because you haven't implemented change notification on the `ViewModel` property. As I say, though - you should be able to get along fine with `Path=DataContext.MyTypes`.

Note: you seem to refer to the property as both `MyTypes` and `ListTypes` in the question - not sure which is correct for your object model.